# Make a Real HTTP Request Using TestCafe

Tags: javascript, testing, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe

Due to complications with automating certain parts of our workflow strictly through the front-end, we need to make an HTTP request before our front-end automation tests run in order to setup test data.

Using the TestCafe docs I tried piecing something together, and while the test runs, the http request is not getting executed.  Here's the code I have:

```
import {Selector, ClientFunction, RequestHook, RequestLogger} from 'testcafe';
import https from 'https';


fixture `Call Create Test Move`
    .before(async ctx => {
        test('test', async t => {
            const executeRequest = () => {
                return new Promise(resolve => {
                    const options = {
                        method: 'POST',
                        uri: 'https://api.com/move/sample',
                        headers: {
                            "X-Company-Secret": "xxxxxxx",
                            "X-Permanent-Access-Token": "xxxxxxx"
                        },
                        body: {
                            companyKey: 'xxxxxx'
                        },
                        json: true
                    };

                    const req = https.request(options, res => {
                        console.log('statusCode:', res.statusCode);
                        console.log('headers:', res.headers);
                        resolve();
                    });

                    req.on('error', e => {
                        console.error(e);
                    });

                    req.end();
                });
            };

            await executeRequest();
        });
    });
```

I'm not super familiar with JS, so probably did something obviously wrong here, just not sure what it is.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

TestCafe runs test code written by the user in the Node.js environment. This means that you can write any custom JavaScript code in your tests and use any third-party library and module to make requests.

The RequestHooks mechanism is intended to mock or log requests from your page, not to send requests. To make an HTTP-request from your test code, you can use the standard `https` nodejs module. Here’s an example:

```
import https from 'https';

const executeRequest = () => {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
        const options = {
            hostname: ' https://api.com/move/sample',
            port:     443,
            path:     '/',
            method:   'POST'
        };

        const req = https.request(options, res => {
            console.log('statusCode:', res.statusCode);
            console.log('headers:', res.headers);
            resolve();
        });

        req.on('error', e => {
            console.error(e);
        });

        req.end();
    });
};

fixture `fixture`
    .page `http://google.com`
    .beforeEach(async t => {
        await executeRequest();
    });

test('test', async t => {
    // test code
});
```

Also, check out these threads where a similar inquiry was discussed:

[How to make post request with data in test-cafe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56427410/how-to-make-post-request-with-data-in-test-cafe)

[Make external request](https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe/issues/2263)

Comment: Tried following the example you linked to, didn't work, possibly due to attempting to combine with a fixture `before` hook?

```fixture \`Call Create Test Move\`
    .before(async ctx => {
        test('test', async t => {```

Comment: Hi,
I updated my answer and added details. Could you please provide your full test code? It looks like your comment was cut down.

Comment: You don't need to put the entire test in the `before` method. See @AlexKamaev's code. Put your tests outside the `before` method.